# How should I partition yearly data in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I'm looking at rearchitecting an existing application and am wondering how best to handle the tables.

At the moment, we have one table per year (data_2009, data_2010 etc). Most queries are done only by year - select sum(sales) from data_2010 where user=10, for example.

Each year has approx 1 million rows; we have 10 years so far, and we're likely to continue indefinitely.

Occasionally, however, calculations should be done over all time. This is currently handled poorly by a separate summary table that is run once a year and has rows for each month for each user (and is then summed/counted etc with the current year). This has various limitations and I'd like to drop the idea of a summary table.

Is it better to have one big table and create views for each year? Or stay with separate tables and have a view for all time? e.g a view that is

select * from data_2005
union
select * from data_2006 
etc.

One question is how indexes will be handled - if I have an index on field "user", say, is used in either scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use one table but use table partitoning and partition on the year. More info about partioning can be found here

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/partitioning.html

Comment: Can I select by specific partitions or do I include date ranges each time? e.g. does "select * from data_2010 where user=10" necessarily become "select * from data where user=10 and date>='2011-04-01' and date<='2012-05-01'" (I'm using financial year, not calendar year unfortunately)?

Comment: Yes that is correct, you would be working with one table but mysql would handle the individual tables "under the hood". From the mySQL Manual: "Partitioning ... enabling you to distribute portions of individual tables across a file system according to rules which you can set largely as needed. In effect, different portions of a table are stored as separate tables in different locations". I would still partition on calendar year for simplicity rather than trying to partition based on financial year.